# How to get the fields of an address from a location record using SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Context: A RESTlet written in SuiteScript v1, but I'll use v2 if I must.

**Important: Solution must work serverside.**

The location record has a field titled Main Address. The field id is mainaddress_text.

When I edit the Main Address field using the NetSuite website it presents me with the normal address editing form with the normal address fields, so it appears that NetSuite stores the address like it does the addresses on, for example, the customer record, in fields called Country, Attention, Addressee, Phone etc.

I want to get the values of these fields, but I can't work out how.

I have loaded the location using

```
location = nlapiLoadRecord('location', locationid)
```

The schema browser (https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/schema/record/location.html) suggests there is a field called mainAddress of type Address.

I have attempted to access the mainAddress field using statements like these:

```
location.getField('mainaddress') //returns null
location.getSubList('mainaddress') //returns null
location.getLineItemCount('mainaddress') //returns -1
location.getFieldValue('mainaddress') //returns null
location.getFieldText('mainaddress') //returns null
```

But no success.

I also tried `location.getLineItemCount('addressbook')` in case there was a field named like in the customer record but that returned -1.

The records browser (https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/location.html) suggests there is a field called addrtext of type Address.

I have attempted to access the addrtext field using statements like these:

```
location.getField('addrtext') //returns null
location.getSubList('addrtext') //returns null
location.getLineItemCount('addrtext') //returns -1
location.getFieldValue('addrtext') //returns null
location.getFieldText('addrtext') //returns null
```

But no success.

The records browser also describes fields called addr1, addr2, addr3, addressee, attention, city and so on.

I have attempted to access those fields using statements like these:

```
location.getFieldValue('attention') //returns null
location.getFieldValue('addressee') //returns null
location.getFieldValue('addr1') //returns null
location.getFieldValue('addr2') //returns null
location.getFieldValue('addr3') //returns null
location.getFieldValue('city') //returns null
location.getFieldValue('state') //returns null
location.getFieldValue('country') //returns null
```

But no success.

The only way I've found to get the address data is using `location.getFieldValue('mainaddress_text')` but that returns the address as one string with the parts of the address delimited by `<br>`-tokens.

How can I get the individual address fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest stringifying the record to see what's in it with `JSON.stringify(location)`. The address fields are normally stored in addr1, etc...

It is possible that the address fields weren't set from the UI. I have seen some scripts that just set the mainaddress_text field, but neglect to change the individual fields as well which causes issues in the long run cause mainaddress_text won't match the other address fields (addr1, addr2, etc...).

You may want to try searching for the address fields, here's how to do it in SS 1.0:

```
var locationSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("location", null,
    [
       ["internalid", "anyof", "2"] //Change internal id
    ], 
    [
        new nlobjSearchColumn("attention", 'address', null),
        new nlobjSearchColumn("addressee", 'address', null),
        new nlobjSearchColumn("address1", null, null),
        new nlobjSearchColumn("address2", null, null),
        new nlobjSearchColumn("address3", null, null),
        new nlobjSearchColumn("city", null, null),
        new nlobjSearchColumn("state", null, null),
        new nlobjSearchColumn("country", null, null),
        new nlobjSearchColumn("zip", null, null),
        new nlobjSearchColumn("phone", null, null)
    ]
);

if (results)
{
    var result = results[0];

    return {
        attention: result.getValue('attention', 'address'),
        addressee: result.getValue('addressee', 'address'),
        address1: result.getValue('address1'),
        address2: result.getValue('address2'),
        address3: result.getValue('address3'),
        city: result.getValue('city'),
        state: result.getValue('state'),
        country: result.getValue('country'),
        zip: result.getValue('zip'),
        phone: result.getValue('phone')
    };
}
```

Comment: The only address fields that JSON.stringify gives me are mainaddress_text and returnaddress_text. The address was set from the UI.

Comment: Weird, on my end when it's set from the UI both mainaddress_text and the individual addr1,etc... fields get set.

Comment: Yeah. A workaround you may want to try is running a search to get the address fields instead.

Comment: How could I do that? I'm happy with any solution that works.

Comment: I just edited my response to include the search example.

Comment: You're awesome! If you don't mind I'll edit your answer to include all the fields I need. Well done.

Comment: Any idea how to get attention and addressee?

Comment: Doing a join with address... fields like this:    new nlobjSearchColumn("attention","address",null), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("addressee","address",null)   To access the values do  result.getValue('addressee','address')

Comment: Very good. How did you know to do it this way? Did you use some documentation?

Comment: I created a saved search using the UI, modified it until I got the results I wanted, then loaded the saved search using suitescript and stringified it in order to look at the columns.

Comment: Nice technique. I'm sure I'll use it in future. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
nlapiLoadRecord("location", locationID, {recordmode: "dynamic"})
.viewSubrecord("mainaddress")
.getFieldValue('addrtext');
```

I opened a Location record in a browser, and opened a console from there to load the nlobjRecord.  Looking at the fields I see there is a `mainaddress2_set` field which is set by a `nlapiViewSubrecord("mainaddress")`

I couldn't make a call to the `viewSubrecord("mainaddress")` from the client side console, but I did create a simple suitelet to load the Location record and print the address.

```
function GET(request, response){
    var r = nlapiLoadRecord("location", "123456", {recordmode: "dynamic"});
    response.write(r.viewSubrecord("mainaddress").getFieldValue('addrtext'));
    response.write(r.viewSubrecord("mainaddress").getFieldValue('addr1'));
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: This gives me an exception on r.viewSubrecord("mainaddress") - \"code\":\"FIELD_1_IS_NOT_A_SUBRECORD_FIELD\",\"details\":\"Field mainaddress is not a subrecord field.\" - but it works for Dave so worth a try for anyone else with the same problem.